# Trying to change a url on a page after a user enters specific text into a field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery right now to change some text on my page when a user enters a specific word into a field on that page.  I've changed text on the page by putting that text in a span and then using this code at the top of the page.  This code is activated when the user enters the appropriate text in the field.

```
jQuery('#msg1').html('(after coupon code)');
```

Essentially, this changes the text in the msg1 span.  I would like to also change a url when a user enters the code into the field.  I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.  Any advice?

Comment: Verify if coupom is correct and after this redirect to a new url?

Comment: Do you want to change `href` value or want to redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to redirect to another URL? It's as simple as:

```
window.location = "http://www.new-url.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to redirect the user after changing the text?

```
location.href = "(url)";
```